# Required field on AR Invoice and Memos causes error when entering AR Payment

Tags: customization, acumatica

I created a simple customization to add a string UDF on the AR Invoices and Memos screen, AR.30.10.00.  I made it required by adding attribute [PXDefault].

Now when I enter cash receipts in AR Payments and Applications, AR.30.20.00, and do not apply the cash to an invoice, the system throws an error saying the UDF is required.  There is no place to enter the UDF on the Payments screen.  The UDF is related to the invoice, not the payment.

Why is the system throwing this error?  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your CustomField was added to the **ARRegister DAC**(extension) instead of the **ARInvoice DAC**(extension).
ARInvoice and ARPayment both inherit from ARRegister, so if you added the Custom Field(required) to ARRegister DAC(extension) then it will be required for both.

If you added the field via the **Data Access** section in the Customization Project, I think it adds it to the ARRegister DAC extension.
On the Customization Tool you could click on **Code** section, click on Plus symbol(**Add**), select **DAC Extension** on File Template, add name and click ok.
This will create a Dac Extension file that you could manipulate and use **ARInvoice** instead of the **ARRegister**.

[image]

Then after saving the file, you will  need to go File->Edit Project Items on top menu.

[image]

There you will need to right click on the Grid area, select Add->Database Table Field:

[image]

Then select the desired DAC (ARInvoice) in your case, with the field name and type (matching fieldname and type used on the DAC Extension file).
Please notice that you do **not need to add "Usr"** to the field, this is automatically added by the Tool.

[image]

Click Ok, **Save and publish**, so the field can be accessible now on the Screen Section.

Answer (score 1):

The PXDefault attribute also checks that the field value is not null before saving to the database. You can adjust this behavior using the PersistingCheck property. Its value indicates whether the attribute should check that the value is not null, check that the value is not null or a blank string, or not check.

```
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

Reference: [PXDefault Attribute](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=2f1b73b5-08c6-4c45-a72f-ffb8561d8aa1)

The DAC you extended is likely used in both screens so you should change the persisting check or set a default value.

You can override your custom field on specific graph where you want/don't want that behavior using CacheAttached event:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
protected virtual void ARTran_UDF_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

Without an explicit default value, fields will be null and raise error on persisting check. To set a non null default value for a string field:

```
[PXDefault("")]
```

Comment: I believe cbetabeta correctly identified your specific issue in his answer.